# How do I successfully import YAJLiOS JSON Framework in to my iOS project?

Tags: objective-c, json, yajl

I'm trying to use the YAJLiOS framework for JSON in my project as I've been told it's the fastest JSON framework to use.

Anyway I've dragged the folder called YAJLiOS.framework in to the Link Binary With Libraries window and added the -ObjC and -load_all tags to Other Linker Flags under appNameTest in Targets.

I've then done;

```
#import <YAJLiOS/YAJL.h>

NSString *JSONString = @"[1, 2, 3]";
NSArray *arrayFromString = [JSONString yajl_JSON];
```

and the second line is throwing "Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

It's driving me crazy, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://rel.me/2009/06/15/yajl-json-parser-objective-c-bindings/